# Ionic release build apk as x86 and x86_64, how to exclude these architectures

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, apk

When I build a release build with ionic, both x86 and x86_64 and included doubling my apk size, how to exclude these architectures ?

I use below command to build

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: Are you getting multiple APK files??

Comment: no, single apk with all libraries together

Comment: Not sure, but google will automatically Sort it when you upload it to PlayStore. your APK size will go down as fr as i know.